# How to update TextView on UI from the class which using runnable interface?

Tags: java, android

```
public class Stopper implements  Runnable {

     private  long mStartTime;
     private volatile int since;
     private Handler handler;
     private TextView tv;
     private Activity activity;
     private Context context;


    /*
    * Constants
    * */
        public static final int MILISEC_TO_MINUTE = 60000;
        public static final int MILISEC_TO_HOUR = 3600000;

    /*
    * Flags
    * */
        private boolean mIsRunning;

        public Stopper(){
          //this.context = context;
            activity = (Activity)context;
            Message message = Message.obtain();
            handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        }
        public void start(){
            mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            mIsRunning = true;


        }
        public void stop(){
            mIsRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run () {
            while (mIsRunning) {
                        since = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime);
                        int hours =  (since / MILISEC_TO_HOUR) % 24; // ms -> h; 360 000= 1[h]
                        int minutes =  (since / MILISEC_TO_MINUTE) % 60;// ms -> min; 60 000[ms] = 1[min]
                        int seconds =  (since / 1000) % 60; //  ms -> s ;1 000[ms] = 1[s] -> (1000 [ms] /1000)%60 = 1[s]
                        int ms =  since % 1000;


                tv.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, ms));


                //((Activity) context).updateTimerText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, ms));
            }
        }
    public void getStooperTextView(TextView textView)
    {
        this.tv = textView;
    }

    public int getSince() {
        return since;
    }
}
```

I read some tutorial about [chronometer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RVzknsdknw). It works fine until I started needing to use chronometer in two diffrent Activity. The below line of code requires returned value.

```
((Activity) context).updateTimerText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, ms));
```

So, I try to use the Handler class, but to do it I need a runnable object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the method [`Activity#runOnUiThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) is what you need

Comment: I may using `runOnUiThread` inside `Activity`. I used `runOnUiThread`, but I don't know how to return value to `Activity` if I have two different in this situation.

Comment: What do you actually need here? Are you trying to reuse the same textview between two different Activities? Because that's wrong. Or do you need to set the time you had on the previous one into the next one?

Comment: I try display stopper inside two different activity (`Activity`,`Activity2`).  This class gives me information about time which I want to put inside the TextView.  Problem is with last line of code `(Activity) context).updateTimerText`. Firsty I need information if activity have method `updateTimerText`, so I can't  only create variable for two different Activity to return it.

Comment: You can try yo use an interface TimerActivity which has the method updateTimer, make Activity1 and Activity2 implement it and then pass it to the Stopper as a listener. You might want to create a setListener(TimerActivity) method to change listeners at runtime